# Qt and Jpeg plugin problem

Tags: qt

When I try to save pixmap in jpg format then I get an error in console QJpegHandler: unable to write image of format 7 and the result image is corrupt.

How to fix this problem?

Qt 4.6.2 on windows mobile. On symbian it works fine without any problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The JpegHandler in Qt 4.6 does not support writing Format_RGB16
You have to convert to RGB888, or better, RGB32
In 4.7 it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the JPEG image plugin is not linked with your executable. To see which image formats are available, try:

```
QImageWriter::supportedImageFormats()
```

See the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qimagewriter.html#supportedImageFormats) for more information. In case JPEG is not supported, build the JPEG plugin that comes with Qt and link it with your application.

Comment: it is linked, supportedImageFormats() - gif, jpeg, jpg, png. I found the same problem here http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2009-10/00750/Re-(Qt-interest)-QImageWriter-says-JPEG-supported-but-won't-write-JPEG-Files.html but when I convert my image to rgb32 this doesn't affect on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the imageformats folder in qt installation with your executable as support dlls.